# How do I cut edges with the knife tool on one mesh and make it match the edges of another one?

Tags: vertices, edges, knife-tool

I'm trying to cut a mesh (the head) with the knife tool so I can connect the second mesh (the white headband) to it easier but I'm having an issue. I want to make the knife cut I'm making match the edges of the headband, but when I try to setup the vertices during the cut by aiming it at the ones from the headband, they don't make a line like they normally would as seen in the second image.

Apologies if the description of the issue is somewhat rough, I'm not very good when it comes to wording these things.[image]
[image]