# How do I snap an existing edge onto a mesh?

Tags: mesh, edges, snapping

I'm trying to snap this edge onto this face so it can countour onto the mesh, but I don't know how to. [image]

Comment: Hello you could use the snap option to make the vertices snap to the faces?

Comment: I tried using the different snapping modes but I couldn't get any of them to make it snap to it properly.

Comment: Could you please tell a bit more about the whole project? Maybe you could cut your object whith the Knife tool, this way you'll be able to get an edge that completely follow the shape

Comment: For the project, I'm making a sort of costume for the character in question (Meowth), what I'm trying to do here is cutting a hole in the shape of a headband model I had made. However, I don't know how to cut the shape on the head so it matches the shape of the edge/vertices of the headband, I've tried the knife tool and I had an issue with that too as seen here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303918/how-do-i-cut-edges-with-the-knife-tool-on-one-mesh-and-make-it-match-the-edges-o